# Sending emails using Amazon AWS SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I have configured aws's ses service but have not been able to use it. My emails are being sent but they are sent through my hosting server (Godaddy) and I would want to send them only through AWS's SES. Pardon me, if I have made a rookie mistake.

Here's what my code looks like

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->ssl = true;
$mail->authentication = true;
$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->setFrom('vaibhav@zigsaw.in', 'Test Email');
$mail->Body = 'Test Email from Zigsaw';
$mail->AddReplyTo('zigsawconsultancy@gmail.com', 'Candidate');
$mail->addAddress('zigsawconsultancy@gmail.com', 'Recruiter');
$mail->Subject = 'Test Email from Zigsaw';
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
echo "Email not sent. " , $mail->ErrorInfo , PHP_EOL;
} 
else 
{
echo "Email sent!" , PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Disclaimer: My file is hosted on a godaddy server and I am trying to send emails through AWS SES.

Comment: Did u get any error?

Comment: Don't just make stuff up and expect it to work: `$mail->ssl = true;` is completely fictional. Base your code on [the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), and use [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @SuneelKumar No Error. 
Like I said, Email was sent & received. But it was sent through my hosting server and not through SES. I would want to send the emails through ses (Email Server Reputation & Volume) 
Could you suggest anything?

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy actually it works, I have done previous with `mail mime`

Comment: ex:
 `$headers = array (
  'From' => SENDER,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);

 $smtpParams = array (
  'host' => SESHOST,
  'port' => SESPORT,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => SESUSERNAME,
  'password' => SESPASSWORD
 );
 $mime = new Mail_mime(); 
 $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
 $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
 $body = $mime->get(); 
 $mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpParams); 
 $result = $mail->send($to, $headers,$body );
 if (PEAR::isError($result)) {
  //echo("Email not sent. " .$result->getMessage() ."\n");
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }`

Comment: @SuneelKumar Could you please suggest what changes I need to make, to make it send emails through the ses authentication ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes - change your ISP to one that doesn't block SMTP.

Comment: @Synchro Thank you. I corrected the fictional stuff and I was able to send an amazon ses email through my localhost. 

Are you suggesting that there is no-way I will be able to use SES through my godaddy hosting?

Comment: Probably not, unless SES has an HTTP API. GoDaddy is cheap for a reason...

Comment: Simple solution, `$mail->Port =587;` or `$mail->Port =2587;` Try those?  SES supports ports other than 25 and these are much less likely to be hijacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy blocks outbound SMTP, but you've not told PHPMailer to use SMTP (so most of your settings do nothing), so it's submitting via the mail() function, using a local mail server, which in GoDaddy's case is their server - so that's why it's going that way. Unfortunately there isn't a way of using external SMTP on GoDaddy, though you can send via their `secureserver.net` relay - but that of course means you can't send using your personal domain because it's forgery and you messages will be spam-filtered or bounced.

If you call:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

PHPMailer will use SMTP and your other settings, though as I said in my comment, you've just invented a bunch of things that will not work, so rewrite your code based on the examples provided, though this won't work on GoDaddy.

If SES has an HTTP API, so you may be able to use that instead, since it will not be subject to GoDaddy's blocking.

Comment: Thank you @Synchro
I used the code on my local server and it worked like a charm. :)